# Как сделать так что бы при наведении на обьект курсор становился другим только при наведении на обьект?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть блок с текстом.При наведении курсора на этот блок он становится указательным,но если я отведу курсор влево,где блока уже нет,курсор так же указательный,но если вниз,то станет обычный,а мне надо что бы он становился указательным только при наведении курсора,пример на фотографии:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: задай определенный курсор только нужному блоку

Comment: нужен код. чтобы понять в чем ошибка

Comment: Ну вот у меня есть <h2 id = 'article1'>1.Неудачный порт Horaizen На ПК  <p>     Дата Публикации - 10.08.2020 </h2> и #article1:hover{cursor: pointer;}

Comment: Добавьте где-нибудь `* { border: 1px solid red; }` — всё будет видно) Скорее всего и справа распространяется всё тот же блок, хоть текста там и нет) Один из вариантов, дать тому блоку `display: inline-block;`